# OCR character segmentation character count for burmese characters

Tags: image-processing, ocr

I am currently making OCR program for physical NRC to convert digital. Here, I am sticking with how can I know the exact number of word count in incoming input segments.

Language is **burmese**. In the first photo, its two character but the first character has opening at his bottom when the other doesn't. I tried with **top down profile** which finds for the black pixels and also I thought plotting histogram would solve the problem but as I said above because of character difference it can't always be right and some words would split. So, I would like to know some methods I can try.

[image: burmese character]

[image: burmese character]

Comment: "physical NRC": what's that ?

Answer (score 0):

Correct segmentation of such aggregates is *impossible* without knowledge of the  possible characters. You need to combine segmentation with recognition.

It is even possible that several solutions exist and in such a case you can't arbitrate without a lexicon, or can't arbitrate at all.

Think of W vs VV.

Comment: Thanks alot sir. I thought there will be a way without recognition of a character. Thanks for your point.

Comment: @KhantThuAung: think of this: I known nothing about Burmese. How can I know where to split ? For your first example, I could split in 8 reasonable ways.